# Sharing implementation of my interface across .NET subsets

Tags: .net, mono, .net-standard

I'm trying to figure out the best way to share a certain class across projects that may refer to different .NET implementations, each having its own subset of libraries.

In the days of yore, we used to have the good ol' .NET Framework. Then came Mono, and Xamarin. The latter introduced the concept of Portable Class Library, which is a library that only uses a subset of .NET so that it can be used on different platforms/.NET implementations. Recently, .NET Core and .NET Standard introduced even more variety to the landscape. I love how .NET Standard is portable to virtually anywhere, but this causes me a design problem.

Traditionally, I would create a class library project with the core logic of my application, then add a front-end project (be it WinForms, WPF, a web application, or a mobile app) that is only concerned with application-level, platform-specific functionality. For example, the library would have the data classes and a `ProductsDatabase` class, defining the connection to the database and the management of data objects; in the front-end project, I'd make a controller that uses that class and produces an HTML page, or the view-model of an Android activity.

However, in a Xamarin PCL, or in a .NET Standard class library, I cannot reference `System.Data.dll`. I can in fact use the `Mono.Data.Sqlite` namespace, for instance (at least in a PCL), but it does not compile as soon as I call `SqliteConnection.Connect()`. Usually, I'd define an interface in my portable library, which I'd implement in the front-end project. However, it means that my platform-specific project would have to implement a MySQL database, a SQLiteDatabase, and who knows how many other things. However, the SQLite database for an Android app should be the same as the one for an iOS app (both through Xamarin), or for any app using Mono. It might be different when moving to a platform that doesn't use Mono, for example a WPF application and an ASP.NET MVC web app. However, you get the point.

So, my question is: what would be the best approach to share code implementations between platform-specific projects? Should I add an intermediate layer, ending up with three of them: one with the most agnostic classes and interfaces, a middle one with the platform-specific but shareable implementations, and the upper one with the actual executable project? Or is there another design pattern that I'm missing?

Comment: I wonder why you cannot use `System.Data.Common` NuGet package, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Data.Common/ref Don't use `System.Data.dll`, as that's still the .NET Framework bit. Your .NET Standard class library can code against most of the common API, while leaving the final connection object creation to the front-end projects. Whether there is a good enough SQLite ADO.NET library that works with such .NET Standard approach, is unknown, but should be another question.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for the tip. This library could solve the problem with database implementation; I still wonder whether there's a technique that can be applied to the general case.

Comment: You could solve this through standard OO design techniques I think. E.g. Use Interfaces and an Abstract Factory to create your concrete implementations?

Comment: @muszeo Of course I can, but I can't see how I can do that in two layers: shared code base, in .NET Standard, and final project, in .NET-whatever. Two final projects, for example, would end up with very similar implementations of feature X - maybe the exact same implementation. I was wondering if I really have to make a third layer, a project-in-the-middle that includes classes implementing feature X.

Comment: Ah I see what you’re asking now. Sadly not really, the only way I think is to inject into the standard library from your framework or core project based on whatever common interfaces you can find. As Lex says there is a common data library and there are other common libraries but it’s by no means comprehensive yet — a bit hit and miss. I suppose you could try inverting the dependency or abstracting it away in a third library as you say, that would at least allow you to tidy it all up in future without impacting your core logic.

Comment: Thanks @muszeo, I was afraid it was like that. I've only scratched the surface of this diverse new .NET implementations, and I hoped there was a more general approach that I didn't know of. I guess I'll have to work with that then.